VBA: Add series Name at *only* the last point of each series in Line Chart Excel
I have a standard line chart in excel with around 80 series on the chart. When using the below code,
  Sub setDataLabels()
   '
   '     sets data labels in all charts
   '
  Dim sr As Series
  Dim cht As ChartObject
  '
 With ActiveSheet
  For Each cht In .ChartObjects
    For Each sr In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        sr.ApplyDataLabels
        With sr.DataLabels
            .ShowCategoryName = False
            .ShowValue = False
            .ShowSeriesName = True
        End With
      Next sr
     Next cht
 End With
 End Sub

'''
This returns the series name on every point of the series, so if series 3 has 1000 data points, i see series 3 series name 1000 times. How can i manipulate this to just return the name of the series once?
Thank you

Instead of ApplyDataLabels to the entire series, just apply it to the last point, as demonstrated in the linked thread.
